# No local SparkleFormation files detected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

So I've been working in sparkleformation and had this issue pop up even though all my files exist:

```
[WARN]: No local SparkleFormation files detected
[ERROR]: Failed to locate any templates!
[FATAL]: Invalid formation file path provided: 
ERROR: IOError: Failed to locate file:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to create this question for future reference.  This is what happens if you create a sparkleformation template and place any code outside of the `Sparkleformation.new` block.  For example this would cause the above failure:

```
yamlfile = YAML.load_file(ENV['YAMLFILE_YML_PATH'])

SparkleFormation.new(:somename, :provider => :aws).load(:base).overrides do
  yamlfile.keys.each { |key| yamlfile[key.to_sym] = yamlfile.delete(key)}
  dynamic!(:someother name, :test_eips, yamlfile)
end
```

This will work:

```
SparkleFormation.new(:somename, :provider => :aws).load(:base).overrides do
  yamlfile = YAML.load_file(ENV['YAMLFILE_YML_PATH'])
  yamlfile.keys.each { |key| yamlfile[key.to_sym] = yamlfile.delete(key)}
  dynamic!(:someother name, :test_eips, yamlfile)
end
```